# Once checkbox is checked auto select text box

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have this JQuery script that requires a user to check a checkbox to be able to type in a text box. Once the checkbox is checked, I want the textbox to be selected automatically, not manually.

This is the JQuery code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#threadTitleCheckbox').click(function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked"))
         $("#threadTitleCheck").removeAttr("disabled");
       else
         $("#threadTitleCheck").attr("disabled" , "disabled");
   });
   });
   </script>
```

This is the HTML code for the checkbox

```
<dl class="ctrlUnit fullWidth">
        <dd><input type="checkbox" id="threadTitleCheckbox" name="threadTitleCheckbox" /><font style="margin-left:5px;">I believe {$forum.title} is the best forum for this topic.</font></dd>
</dl>
```

This is the HTML code for the text box

```
<dt><label for="threadTitleCheck">{xen:phrase title}:</label></dt>
<dd><input type="text" name="threadTitleCheck" class="textCtrl titleCtrl" id="threadTitleCheck" maxlength="100" autofocus="true" disabled placeholder="{xen:phrase thread_title}..." value="{$title}"
                data-liveTitleTemplate="{xen:phrase create_thread}: <em>%s</em>" /></dd>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#threadTitleCheckbox').on('change', function(){
       $("#threadTitleCheck").prop("disabled", !this.checked).focus();
   });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/88ufV/)

Comment: I was heading down this method but for some reason in FF if there's a value in the input it doesn't get selected (highlighted) as it does in Chrome.

Comment: @j08691 - That's strange, it does seem to work for me in FF ?

Comment: Hmmm. So in http://jsfiddle.net/82QHn/ if you check the checkbox the value foo becomes highlighted? Weird, not for me. Works in Chrome though.

Comment: Oh, now I think I get it, the value doesn't get selected, the textbox is just focused, I thought that was what the OP meant with "textbox to be selected automatically", if not there should probably be a `select()` chained on after the `focus()` ?

Comment: It worked me in chrome thanks! But I would like it too work in firefox too

Comment: @Matthew - If the answer works as expected in Chrome, it should work in all other browsers as well. We're just debating wether or not it should also select the text in the input, and not just focus it.